# Mealybug infection or not?

Tags: identification, pests, succulents

I bought a succulent from a huge display advertised as "succulent, mix". There were few types and I liked this one because it looks like it has a spider web on it. But after showing the picture to my mother she said it is probably infested.

I googled succulent infestations and mealybug symptoms look like this. But I took some of this white things off and there's nothing beneath it, nothing seems to be moving.

I'm new at all this plant owning, so I don't know what to do. Is this a problem with the plant or just that kind of species? How to solve it if it's a problem? How to take care of it if it's normal plant? And if it's a problem how to know if it spread on other plants?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen your kind of succulent before, or mealybugs, so I'm just guessing here. It looks like your plant may be a normal healthy plant that is growing fuzz from the ends of its leaves. Like you said, it doesn't look like there are any bugs on the plant. The fuzz is densest where the leaf ends are curled closest together, but there's still fuzz on the outer tips of some of the larger leaves, which makes me think it may be a natural part of your plant.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much, when I used fuzz as a keyword I got similar plants and after going through some pictures I found one that looks like what I have, Sempervivum Fuzzy Wuzzy. Sadly I removed some of it while checking for the bugs, so hopefully it will grow again

Comment: That's great that you identified your plant! It will probably do just fine even if it is missing some of its fuzz, I'd think.